# popover controller with tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a TableView with a bar button item. When I click bar button it's show the PopOver menu. when I click the Popover menu items perform some actions (like tableview data with specific items) 
I want use PopOver menu as a Filter type:

This is the code :

**View Controller code**

```
@IBAction func ButtonClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "POP1", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier ==  "POP1"            
    {
        let dest = segue.destination

        if let pop =  dest.popoverPresentationController
        {                
            pop.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = fruitName

    return cell
}
```

**PopOVER Code:**

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

```
    return 1

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return data.count

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "POP", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var selectedItem = indexPath
    print (selectedItem.row)

}
```

[image]

when I click one in Popover menu it should show the count of words starting with each letter (1 from A, 2 from B) displayed on view controller table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a completion closure or delegate method to achieve your goal. This is a useful [lib](https://github.com/linhcn/LCUIComponents) using completion closure with generic data type for you to freely get/set table view data source as key-value tuples.

For delegation, you can do something as follows:

```
protocol PopoverViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didSelectData(_ result: String)
}

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PopoverViewControllerDelegate?

    //...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let selectedItem = arrayData[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.didSelectData(selectedItem)
    }
}
```

and then in your current view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PopoverViewControllerDelegate {

    // ...

    func didSelectData(_ result: String) {
        // Update fruits array
        tableView.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: if I can click the "one" in popover menu it should display main table view data "Apple", "Apricot" how can I update my main tableview

Comment: After selecting data, you need to update your *fruits* array as it's your table view's data source, and then reload the table view.

Comment: In your `ViewController` have you set something like `popoverViewController.delegate = self` in which `popoverViewController` is an instance of PopoverViewController?

Comment: let vc = POPOVERTableViewController()
 vc.delegate = self    Idid this then also not calling  func didSelectData(_ result: String)
    {
        print("data is print")
    }

Comment: Correct. If the delegate method is not called, try using break point and/or `print` to see at which part of the code it's not running through. Remember that the `didSelectData` should be called after you select data in your table view of the POPOVERTableViewController.

Comment: sorry Yar it's not calling after POPOVERTableView select I put break statement but did selectData is not calling wer I did mistake

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint inside `didSelectRowAt`? If you did and it gets called, but `delegate?.didSelectData(selectedItem)` did not, I probably need to see your code to track the issue.

Comment: I set the break point at delegate?.didSelectData(selectedItem) after it has to hit the didSelectData function. this function is not calling

Comment: I'm not sure if you forgot to add `PopoverViewControllerDelegate` to your view controller, but you may want to show your edited code for us to track down the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214007/protocol-delegate-method-is-not-called-in-swift this is my delegate method with out tableview this is also not calling

Comment: @nagarajukankanala I responded to the other question. Btw, if the problems has been solved/on the right track, please mark them as answered before moving on.