# Protocol Delegate Method is not called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Protocol delegate method is not called..

**First View controller code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,customDelegate {

  var seconviewcontroller : SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
  @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    seconviewcontroller.delegate = self
}
func didSelectData(_ result: String) {

    Label.text = result
  print("Didselect Data Call")

}
```

**Second view controller code**

```
import UIKit
protocol customDelegate: class {
    func didSelectData(_ result: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
     var delegate: customDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var secondbutton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func secondbuttonclick(_ sender: Any) {
     let selectedItem = "naga"

     delegate?.didSelectData(selectedItem)
}
```

how to call the   func didSelectData pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically in line  `var seconviewcontroller : SecondViewController = SecondViewController()` is different from your pushing view controller instance.

You are making a separate instance of `SecondViewController` so you have done delegate self at the time of pushing with pushes object like that

```
let secondVCInstance = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
secondVCInstance.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVCInstance, animated: true)
```

**NOTE: - EVERY OBJECT HAS ITS OWN PROPERTIES**

Answer (score 4):

As you've already used segue for navigating between views. You can also use that for this example. I give the following as a code sample so that you can track back yourself to detect issue in your code.

[image]

**First View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondVCDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondVC.delegate = self
        }
    }        

    func didSelectData(_ result: String) {
        label.text = result
        print(result)
    }
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
import UIKit

protocol SecondVCDelegate: class {
    func didSelectData(_ result: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didSelectData("My result")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries, glad it helps.

Comment: I have to pass the data with first view controller to second view controller I know segue is there but I have to use protocol delegate pls help how to do

Comment: I had count of the students in First view controller I have to  pass that data count to second view controller how to pass that with out segue/ user defaults  I want print that count at second view controller

Comment: if I can take the instance as Global i will access the count of the student in another controller

Comment: There are various ways of passing data from 1 view controller to the other. If you don't you segue anymore, but use navigation, from the first VC you can simply do `seconVC.dataList = self.dataList` and `navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

First View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondVCDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondVC.delegate = self
        }
    }        

    func didSelectData(_ result: String) {
        label.text = result
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Second View Controller

```
import UIKit

protocol SecondVCDelegate: class {
    func didSelectData(_ result: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didSelectData("My result")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```