# Send image to new view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a small app that displays images in a wallpaper gallery. When the user selects an image, they can set the image to the `MainViewController` or return to the gallery of images to set a different image.

**My question is:**

How do I send an image from my `DetailsViewController` to the `MainViewController` whilst remaining on `DetailsViewController`. I don't want the user to segue to the `MainViewController`.

Is that making any sense? I've been at this for days and can't understand how to do it.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImageView: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        categoryImageView.image = image
        categoryImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you don't want to navigate to `MainViewController` why do you want to send an image to it?

Comment: It's part of the design, remaining in the images gallery.

Comment: As the `MainViewController` won't be showing, the image won't be visible to  users anyway. Why do you want to send it to the `MainViewController`?

Comment: Because it's a wallpaper.

Comment: Still think you need to navigate to the `MainViewController` at some point, but anyway I guess using `delegate` is what you want. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215000/7113238 even it segues back to the first view controller but it has the concept.

Comment: So how would you do it? I have seen a couple examples, but as I'm only 4 months old to code, I get confused if the code samples haven't used the same naming as I have. I also had a burger for lunch which never helps my brain power.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate. 
More info here [The Swift Programming Language. Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

In DetailController:

```
import UIKit

//define protocol
protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSelectImage(_ image: UIImage)
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImageView: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage!

    //delegate var
    var delegate: DetailViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        categoryImageView.image = image
        categoryImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    }

    //the function that is called when you select an image in detail Controller
    //or you can use collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) instead
    func setImageToTheMain(_ image: UIImage) {

        delegate?.didSelectImage(image)
    }

}
```

In MainViewController:

Option 1) if you're using segues

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "your segue to the detail identifier" {

        let destinationController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        //Set MainViewController as a delegate for DetailViewController
        //So it will receive data from DetalVC
        destinationController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Option 2) if you're using presentation

```
func goToDetail() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Detail storyboard name or Main", bundle: nil)

    guard let detailController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Detail controller identifier") as? DetailViewController else {
        return
    }

    detailController.delegate = self

    self.present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When your Master was set as a delegate, you need to call a method that was created in the protocol:

```
extension MainViewController: DetailViewControllerDelegate{

    func didSelectImage(_ image: UIImage) {

        //set image to the Master Controller outlet here
        //something like this:
        yourImageView.image = image
    }
}
```